# Rails error message when parsing a JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I have a method that gets artists top albums from Lastfm

```
    def get_albums
        @albums = Array.new
        @artistname.each do |name|
            s = LastFM::Artist.get_top_albums(:artist => name, :limit => 1)
            r = JSON.parse(s.to_json)['topalbums']['album']['name']
            @albums.push r                      
            end
    end
```

This method work fine and returns an array of albums for each artist as long as the artist has a top album, if they don't I get a NoMethodError undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

What I'm trying to do is add a check when parsing to try and get pass this NoMethodError but can't seem to figure it out. I tried this:

```
    def get_albums
        @albums = Array.new
        @artistname.each do |name|
            s = LastFM::Artist.get_top_albums(:artist => name, :limit => 1)
            r = JSON.parse(s.to_json)['topalbums']['album']['name']
            if['topalbums']['album']['name'].empty?
                @albums.push(@artistname + "does not have a top album")
            else
                @albums.push r                      
            end
                end

    end
```

Which gives me a TypeError can't convert String into Integer message

Any ideas how I could fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is not a concat operator in ruby.

What you are attempting to use is the `<<` operator.

```
@albums.push(@artistname << " does not have a top album")
```

Comment: Cheers I've changed the + to << but I'm still getting the TypeError cannot convert String to integer on this line of code if['topalbums']['album']['name'].empty?

Comment: Are you actually getting the error on this line of code?

Comment: Also, `if['topalbums']['album']['name'].empty?` doesn't make any sense. You need to specify the hash that you are searching through.

Comment: Change that to `if r.empty?`

Comment: Tried that but getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for r = JSON.parse(s.to_json)['topalbums']['album']['name']

Comment: meaning the JSON that is being returned is not an array.

Comment: Sorry I must be missing something I still don't understand how I can fix it, the method works perfectly if the artist has a top album it's only when they don't that I get the error. This is part of the response from Lastfm that works: {"topalbums"=>{"album"=>"name"=>"Friday Night in Dixie"}} However, if there is no top album as in this part of the response: {"topalbums"=>{"#text"=>"\n    ", "artist"=>"Mark Chestnut"}} it throws the error?